# How do you add a package repo with https url with saltstack?

Tags: salt-stack

I'm only a beginner with SaltStack. I can see there is a pkgrepo module that can be used to set up a package repo in order to install a package from it.

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.pkgrepo.html

i am trying with below code, but its throwing error, on salt site it's not clear how can we use url.

```yaml
base:       
  pkgrepo.managed:   
  - name: https://xxxxx/artifactory/api/pypi/CLOUD-pypi-virtual/simple   

  python-pip:   
    pkg.installed
```

Error:

```
    ----------
          ID: base
    Function: pkgrepo.managed
        Name: https://xxxx/artifactory/api/pypi/CLOUD-pypi-virtual/simple
      Result: False
     Comment: Failed to configure repo 'https://xxxx/artifactory/api/pypi/CLOUD-pypi-virtual/simple': The
repo does not exist and needs to be created, but either a baseurl or a
mirrorlist needs to be given
     Started: 12:15:00.874579
    Duration: 917.356 ms
     Changes:
----------
```

Comment: Which packaging system? The docs you linked have a separate section for each one.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that you need to supply a `baseurl` or `mirrorlist` for a repo to be created.

At the very minimum you need a `name`, and one of `baseurl` or `mirrorlist`.

For example, considering that you have a `baseurl`:

```yaml
install-python-pip:
  pkgrepo.managed:
  - name: python-pip
  - humanname: PyPI package index       # optional human friendly name
  - baseurl: https://xxxxx/artifactory/api/pypi/CLOUD-pypi-virtual/simple

  pkg.installed:
  - name: python-pip
```